How do I get Docker Compose to remount CIFS/Samba volumes after network errors?
I run a Jellyfin media server inside a Docker container started by Docker Compose. Jellyfin's media is stored on an CIFS/Samba volume which I have Docker Compose mount into the container automatically:
services:
  jellyfin:
    image: jellyfin/jellyfin
    container_name: jellyfin
    # […]
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: jellyfin-media
        target: /media
        read_only: true
    restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
  jellyfin-media:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: cifs
      device: "${MEDIA_SAMBA_ADDRESS}"
      o: "addr=${MEDIA_HOST},username=${MEDIA_USER},password=${MEDIA_PASSWORD},file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,ro"

This has worked fine for months. A few days ago, however, Jellyfin suddenly ceased to work and it turns out this was because the mount failed:
$ docker logs jellyfin
[…]
[09:57:51] [ERR] [61] Emby.Server.Implementations.Library.LibraryManager: Error in PlaylistResolver resolving /media/music
System.IO.IOException: Host is down : '/media/music'
   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1.Init()
[…]

$ docker exec --tty -i jellyfin sh
# ls -l
ls: cannot access 'media': Host is down
total 60
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    7 May 13 00:00 bin -> usr/bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jan 28  2024 boot
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root 4096 Oct  1 20:06 cache
drwxr-xr-x   8 root root 4096 Jun 18 20:53 config
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  340 Jun 19 20:09 dev
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 19 20:09 etc
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jan 28  2024 home
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 19 20:09 jellyfin
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    7 May 13 00:00 lib -> usr/lib
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    9 May 13 00:00 lib64 -> usr/lib64
d?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 May 13 00:00 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 May 13 00:00 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 202 root root    0 Jun 19 20:09 proc
drwx------   1 root root 4096 Jun 19 20:10 root
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 May 13 00:00 run
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    8 May 13 00:00 sbin -> usr/sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 May 13 00:00 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root    0 Jun 18 20:57 sys
drwxrwxrwt   1 root root 4096 Jun 19 20:09 tmp
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 May 13 00:00 usr
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 May 13 00:00 var

I suspect this might have been due to the network connection dropping temporarily. In any case, running docker compose restart fixed things for now. However, is there an easy way to get Docker Compose to remount the Samba volume automatically whenever the network fails? Or will I have to resort to some mechanism outside Docker Compose, like autofs or remounting via systemd?
